# What is the widest localized price string in the App Store?

Tags: ios, localization, app-store

I am looking to figure out what App Store locale results in the widest localized price string so that I can ensure there is enough room in a UI element to display it without clipping.

Marco Arment posed this same question on Twitter in January 2012 and followed up later that day with [this tweet](https://twitter.com/marcoarment/status/156418070443851777), indicating that CHF is the widest string:

> Sounds like localized CHF is the widest at e.g. "CHF 10.00" (thanks [@timohetzel](https://twitter.com/timohetzel)). Know of any wider ones?

Is this still true today?

Unfortunately, Twitter is an awful archive, and while I found his tweets, it will not show me any replies.

Comment: I think that's still accurate - there aren't many that are longer than a single character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CHF` does seem to be the longest (Switzerland), other symbols longer than a single character are `Kr` (Sweden / Norway) and `KR` (Denmark).